# Adding entries to a row according to a filter in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, mask

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [' Compound Mortar ',
                                   ' lime plaster ',
                                    'mortar Screed ',
                                    ' Gypsum Plaster ',
                                    ' Gypsum Plaster 2',
                                    ' lime Plaster 233',
                                    'Clay 23',
                                    'Clay plaster Mortar']})
```

I am using a filter to search for certain words. My approach so far has been this:

```
dataFrame["Type"] =  ""

mask1 = dataFrame["Name"].apply(lambda x: "Mortar".casefold() in "".join(x).casefold())
```

I would like that if the filtered word is present in the "NAME" column, the searched word is added in the "Type" column. It could happen that more words were to be found. For example, if you used a new filter with the word "Glue".
In this case the corresponding row in the column "Type" should contain both keywords found. (A list would be fine)

Answer (score 2):

You can just do `str.findall`

```
import re
word = ['Mortar','Clay']
dataFrame['new'] = dataFrame.Name.str.findall('|'.join(word),flags=re.IGNORECASE).map(','.join)
dataFrame
Out[776]: 
                  Name          new
0     Compound Mortar        Mortar
1        lime plaster              
2       mortar Screed        mortar
3      Gypsum Plaster              
4     Gypsum Plaster 2             
5     lime Plaster 233             
6              Clay 23         Clay
7  Clay plaster Mortar  Clay,Mortar
```

Comment: Thank you. What if I wanted to add a second column in the search? In the sense that I would have to search for keywords in two columns at the same time.

Comment: I'm using this method: (dataFrame["col1"] + dataFrame["col2"]).str

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dataFrame['Type'] = pd.concat([dataFrame['Name'].str.contains(word, case=False).map({True: word, False: ''}) for word in words], axis=1).agg(list, axis=1).str.join(',').str.strip(',')
```

Output:

```
>>> dataFrame
                  Name         Type
0     Compound Mortar        Mortar
1        lime plaster              
2       mortar Screed        Mortar
3      Gypsum Plaster              
4     Gypsum Plaster 2             
5     lime Plaster 233             
6              Clay 23         Clay
7  Clay plaster Mortar  Mortar,Clay
```

Comment: In position 7 you only get the word "Clay", instead, I would like to get both words. Thank you

Comment: Check the answer now :)

Comment: Sometimes i get this result: [Mortar,,,,,,,,,,,,,mineral]

Comment: Strange - do you have some words in your words list that are empty strings?

Comment: Here I perhaps describe the problem better: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71468741/creating-a-list-of-keywords-by-scrolling-through-a-dataframe-python