# Creating a list of keywords by scrolling through a dataframe (python)

Tags: python, regex, list, dataframe, findall

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame({'Name': (("' VerbundmÃ¶rtel ', ' Compound Mortar ', ' Malta per stucchi e per incollaggio '"),
                                   ("' StoLevell In Absolute ', ' StoLevell In Absolute '"),
                                    ("' Anhydrit-FlieÃ\x9festrich ', ' Anhydrite Flowing Screed ', ' Massetto a base di anidrite '"),
                                    ("' AnsetzmÃ¶rtel SLP ', ' Attachment mortar SLP ', ' Malta minerale adesiva SLP + iQ-Fix '"),
                                    ("' AQUAPANEL Cement MÃ¶rtel ', ' AQUAPANEL Cement Mortar '"),
                                    ("' Armatop por ', ' Armatop por '"),
                                    ("' Armatop por ', ' Armatop por '")),
                         
                            "File_name":(( "esiveCoveringPlaster_2" ),
                                        ("AdhesiveMortarLevellInForAEVERO_720"),
                                        ("AnhydriteFlowingScreed_20"),
                                        ("AnsetzmoertelSLPRemmers_21"),
                                        ("AquaboardMoertel_655"),
                                        ("ArmatopPor479korr_797"),
                                        ("ArmatopPor_479"))})
```

And the keywords I am searching for:

```
words = ['Mortar','hist','lime',
        'loam','adhesive','clay',
        'cement','insulation','sealing',
        'light','base', 'glue', 
        'gyps', 'mineral', 'fine',
        'Levelling', 'mould','Silicate'
        'Porous','Concrete','screed',
        'Rendering', 'Silicate','Renovation'
        'Perlite','Waterproof','Porous',
        'Old', 'Inside', 'por']
```

I would like to obtain a list of keywords. I am trying two methods but am not getting the desired result

## METHOD 1

```
test = ((dataFrame['Name'] + dataFrame['File_name'])).str.findall('|'.join(words),flags=re.IGNORECASE).map(','.join)
```

## RESULT 1

```
0   Mortar
1   Adhesive,Mortar
2   Screed,base,Screed
3   mortar,mineral
4   Cement,Cement,Mortar
5   por,por,Por
6   por,por,Por
```

## METHOD 2

```
test = pd.concat([(dataFrame['Name'] + dataFrame['File_name'])
               .str
               .contains(word, case=False)
               .map({True: word, False: ''})
               for word in words], axis=1).agg(list, axis=1).str.join(',').str.strip(',')
```

## RESULT 2

```
0   Mortar
1   Mortar,,,,adhesive
2   base,,,,,,,,,screed
3   Mortar,,,,,,,,,,,,,mineral
4   Mortar,,,,,,cement
5   por
6   por
```

My goal is to find the words in the two columns. The new column will then be added to the dataframe. I expect a list of words in the results:

```
words = [['Mortar'],
        ['Mortar', 'adhesive'],
        ['Base', 'screed'],
        ['Mortar', 'mineral'],
        ['Mortar', 'cement'],
        ['por'],
        ['por']]
```

I am creating scatterplots and the function "hue" will have to refer to the second column. I hope I have made myself clear enough.

Comment: and what do you expect?

Comment: I expect a list of words in the results. 1 [Mortar, adhesive].

Comment: I have added what I would like to achieve in the question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you only want to find the occurrence of the words in your list `words` in your dataframe. Your exact problem is a bit unclear.

```
words = ['Mortar','hist','lime',
        'loam','adhesive','clay',
        'cement','insulation','sealing',
        'light','base', 'glue', 
        'gyps', 'mineral', 'fine',
        'Levelling', 'mould','Silicate'
        'Porous','Concrete','screed',
        'Rendering', 'Silicate','Renovation'
        'Perlite','Waterproof','Porous',
        'Old', 'Inside', 'por']
pattern = "|".join(words)

regexW = re.compile(pattern)
regexW.findall("".join(str(df.values)))

['Mortar', 'Mortar', 'base', 'mineral', 'Mortar', 'por', 'por', 'por', 'por']
```

Comment: I have added what I would like to achieve in the question